# Why was this question "Norm of the product of two regular ideals of an order of an algebraic number field" put on hold?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have no idea why [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555640/norm-of-the-product-of-two-regular-ideals-of-an-order-of-an-algebraic-number-fie) should be put on hold.
Please let me know the reason.
Otherwise I cannot improve it.

**EDIT(Nov. 12, 2013)**
I rephrased **Remark** to make it shorter and clearer.
And I changed the spoiler to **My method** and made it visible.

Comment: Out of my own curiosity (and also because I am quite ignorant of algebraic number theory): You state in the question that you asked it to have some reference when answering other questions.  Do you have any concrete examples of questions currently on math.SE for which this proposition would be useful?  (Even better would be questions that you yourself have not asked.)

Comment: @ArthurFischer The result is used in the following question of mine which is important in the ideal theory of orders in quadratic number fields.
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556288/decomposition-of-a-primitive-regular-ideal-of-a-quadratic-order
I'm not sure if there are such questions other than mine *right now*. I haven't checked it thoroughly. However, it has a close connection with solving diophantine equations of the form $m = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$.
Hence it is closely related to the theory of integral binary quadratic forms.

Comment: I can see no reason why it was closed. Perhaps people didn't like you pointing out that asking questions which you know the answer to is "allowed" (of course, there is no "allowed" -not really- as for all practical purposes it is up to the community). However, this wasn't a "pretend you're on Jeopardy!" question, but rather one about alternative proofs. Which is fine as far as I am concerned...

Comment: (That said, you have posted *a lot* of questions in this vein recently. Perhaps, as one of the comments to these many questions suggested, you would find a blog useful? However, I don't think posting lots of questions is a reason to close them...close votes should be given on the basis of quality not quantity.)

Comment: I have refrained from downvoting /voting to close Makoto Kato's questions lately, but I understand the irritation of many. Opening a metathread on each and every single thing is kinda pointless, because nothing new is going to come to light. Also the "rule" about answering one's own question and/or asking a question you know an answer to was, IIRC, not met with approval by Math.SE community. IIRC the provision winning a lot of support said that this is ok,  only if it is something that would **startle** the community, i.e. would be a particularly sleek solution unknown to most of us.

Comment: As a consequence of that reaction anyone posting a question knowing its answer (and later also posting an answer) runs the risk of disproval of others, if the question/answer isn't as brilliant as expected.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, but these questions were not simply "this is my answer", they were more "do you have a different way of doing this?" Which is related, but fundamentally different and shouldn't really be frowned upon in the same way.

Comment: @user: So we have to come up with multiple ways to frown upon M.K. ?? I'd rather just vote and move on.

Comment: @TheChaz I'd rather the community stopped closing his questions for reasons I cannot fathom. I mean, annoying people on meta doesn't warrant closing questions on main, no? There is *nothing wrong* with the question, and yet it is closed. The challenge is to come up with one way to frown upon him...

Comment: I agree; while OP may be a PITA on occasion, I'd rather just treat his contributions on the main site at face value. It's all over my head anyhow :)

Comment: Please judge the merit of a question on its content rather than who posted it.  Nothing about this question warrants its closure.

Comment: @Alexander: I'm not saying that people shouldn't give a second chance. But when someone has breached the trust of more than a handful of people (to the point that you can say that it became an actual issue for the community to deal with), then the user must first try to bridge that gap before they are given any actual leeway. The OP did not do **anything** to bridge that gap, with the exception of opening uncountably many meta threads and claiming that "this is your opinion" or "SE has this policy, and I don't care that you say it's invalid here" when people pointed out his behavior. [...]

Comment: [cont.] I would be very happy to hear your suggestion as to how to deal with someone who claims they want to hear criticism, but really just want to hear "You're absolutely right". Moreover when that someone bombards the meta site with every slight booboo they have, to the point that people no longer bother to try and communicate with him. I posted one comment on a recent thread, and I regretted it soon after. Please, enlighten me, what do you think people should do in that sort of situation when words seem to no longer have any effect?

Comment: (And with the above comments and this one I am through responding to this thread, in particular to the OP with whom I am trying to minimize all interaction or contact. I will, of course, follow closely the comments to this thread.)

Comment: I don't see "I dislike the poster's previous meta questions" on [this page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions). I won't argue whether or not the linked question reflects a change in OP's character because it doesn't matter- *this particular question* is fine. I understand and respect your frustration, but community moderation tools are not venues to express ad hominem opinions.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber I disagree. I see plenty of problems with the question (especially with the original version, which was the one closed). The OP asks a question, and then says that he might have a solution, but only wishes to post a hint as to what that might look like. That is not the sort of question that is generally welcomed on this site.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Right, I'm referring only to the current, most recent version of the question.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber But that was not the one closed, and the question was not why it had not been reopened (in which case the correct action would of course have been to ask in the thread for reopen requests). Instead, the OP did what he always does and opened another meta thread, for which he was awarded with a moderator reopening the question as 4'th rather than as 5'th voter. After seeing the solution the OP had, I see no reason why he would feel it necessary to have it as a separate question or why he wants another proof, as this one is less than 2 lines.

Comment: I neither close nor reopen questions here (other than transport them to other sites or in a few cases of obvious duplicates), but I remember a [discussion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4652/where-is-the-fine-line-between-using-and-misusing) from more than a year ago in which the opinion has been expressed that one should not use MSE as ones personal blog or sketchpad. If one thinks this is a legitimate ground for closing questions, this could only be seen in the context of other questions. MK's behavior is certainly very consistent with him using MSE as a sketchpad.

Comment: I voted to close the original question. I don't think that MSE is the place to write a blog about algebraic number theory; if you'd like to do that, there are more appropriate places for it, such as ProofWiki or your own personal blog. It seems that your aim is to make a large collection of results about this field of study, using MSE as a platform to publish it all; while the goal is laudable, I don't believe that this is the correct place to do it.

Comment: @T.Bongers As I wrote to you several times, I'm not only answering my own questions, but also *I'm asking alternative proofs*.
I think this site is an appropriate place to ask such questions.

Comment: @T.Bongers I just followed your suggestions. 
`[@MakotoKato You have been told, by several people; I agree with Alexander Gruber's suggestions about tagging and using spoiler boxes. My objection is not that you know the answer and are asking the question; my objection is that your questions frequently misrepresent your understanding of the question, in my opinion. –  T. Bongers Nov 2 at 19:48 
]`
`[@MakotoKato Yes, if you were to represent your knowledge and understanding of the question honestly, then I don't think I'd have a problem with your recent questions. –  T. Bongers Nov 2 at 20:09]`

Comment: @AlexanderGruber: Please be careful to distinguish between the merit of a question, and all of the other factors that influence whether or not a question should be closed. e.g. Makoto Koto certainly does not qualify for the "let's give the poster a generous amount of leeway while they adapt to the community norms" credit.

Comment: @MakotoKato When I made that comment,  you had only posted a very few of these questions. Now that  you've posted a huge number and it seems that you're trying to write an entire collection of proofs, my opinion has changed.

Comment: @T.Bongers StackExchange not only allows such questions, but explicitly encourages them.
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/
You are free to disagree with the policy.
However, you need *positive* reasons why they should be banned when you ban them.
Just because you don't like them cannot be a proper reason to ban them.

Comment: @MakotoKato You've cited this policy over and over again. Based on the votes and feedback you've received, the community disagrees. There's a *significant* difference between asking a question for which you know the answer, and trying to write a compendium of proofs for algebraic number theory. I have no objections to someone asking a question in good faith looking for alternative proofs, but I believe that using M.SE as a platform to publish so many proofs is misusing the site.

Comment: @T.Bongers As I said, you need positive reasons why they should be banned.
In other words, you need to point out what negative effects they have on this site.
On the other hand, I can point out several positive effects they have on it.
For example, any member(including me) can use the results or proofs to answer other questions.
You can refer to a blog to answer a question, but it may cease to exist in any time.

Comment: @MakotoKato I've given a number of reasons. This is M.SE, not arXiv, ProofWiki, Wikipedia, or a personal blog; as such I don't think that your questions are within the scope of the website. Based on the community response to your posts, I'm far from alone in this feeling. If you wish to use M.SE in a way that doesn't agree with the established community norms, why are you surprised that the community doesn't give such a great response?

Comment: @Makoto: What answer on MSE refers to this question?

Comment: @Makoto: Your question doesn't look like a question. It looks like an excerpt from a reference book, a meta discussion, a node in a singly linked list, and an extra sentence with a question mark thrown in somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @T.Bongers `[There's a significant difference between asking a question for which you know the answer, and trying to write a compendium of proofs for algebraic number theory.]`
The site officially encourages publishing an idea as long as it is presented in a form of a question and answer. What's wrong with asking, say, 100 such questions?
In other words, what's wrong with doing 100 things if each one is encouraged?

Comment: @Makoto: Scale. Even water is deadly if you drink too much of it!

Comment: No, MSE does not explicitly encourage asking and answering ones own questions. The text you keep citing is from the general stackexchange FAQ (as has been pointed out to you on countless occations). Different sites on the stackexchange network have different policies on specific issues. You are well aware of this as you have been told many times, and yet you keep ignoring everything you are told and doing whatever you please.

Comment: @T.Bongers I repeat. You need to point out what *negative* effects my questions have on this site to ban them. You just keep saying I better post them in other sites. That cannot be a proper reason to ban them.

Comment: You can repeat that as many times as you like (you have certainly repeated it many times now), that does not make it any more true.

Comment: To those of you who voted to close my questions, I am asking *alternaive proofs* in my questions.
You people seem to think I believe all of my propositions are correct.
This is simply not true.
For example, I began to realize [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554971/determination-of-the-prime-ideals-lying-over-an-odd-prime-in-a-quadratic-order) is not correct.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft `[that does not make it any more true.]`
OK, please elaborate on why you think it is not true.

Comment: Just being curious, do you people who downvoted or voted to close my questions understand the problems and their importance in the theory of integral binary quadratic forms?

Comment: Makoto, questioning the competence of m.se voters is not going to incline anyone to look on your questions with favor.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft `[No, MSE does not explicitly encourage asking and answering ones own questions. The text you keep citing is from the general stackexchange FAQ (as has been pointed out to you on countless occations). Different sites on the stackexchange network have different policies on specific issues. You are well aware of this as you have been told many times, and yet you keep ignoring everything you are told and doing whatever you please.]`

I think the *general* stackexchange FAQ applies to each stackexchange site.
Otherwise what's the purpose of the *general* FAQ?

Comment: @GerryMyerson `[Makoto, questioning the competence of m.se voters is not going to incline anyone to look on your questions with favor.]`
It has nothing to do with competence. It has to do with one's interests. For example, I have no interest in axiomatic set theory, so I have no idea what forcing is.
I asked them because the main interests of some of them who voted to close my question are set theory or real analysis both of which have nothing to do with algebraic number theory.

Comment: One could indeed ask about the wisdom of a "general FAQ" that contradicts the norms of specific SE sites. But, in any case, it is clear from the comments here that on *this site*, askers should avoid posts that would be better put on a personal blog or on the arXiv.

Comment: @CarlMummert `[But, in any case, it is clear from the comments here that on this site, askers should avoid posts that would be better put on a personal blog or on the arXiv.]`

Even if this is correct(I don't think so), I don't think my questions are better put on a personal blog or on the arXiv because I'm asking *alternative proofs*.

Comment: @MakotoKato You have (many times) insisted that most of your questions belong to the area of elementary number theory. Are you seriously claiming that a professional mathematician whose main academic qualifications are set theory or real analysis is likely to be unable to understand elementary number theory questions?

Comment: @OldJohn Please see the tag of my question.

Comment: @Makoto: If you are asking for "*alternative proofs*", why do you write answers yourself? That seems to go against your argument that you are genuinely interesd in other answers. E.g.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552516/canonical-basis-of-an-ideal-of-a-quadratic-order/560453#560453 http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556643/criterion-on-whether-a-given-ideal-of-a-quadratic-order-is-regular-or-not/560914#560914 http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555640/norm-of-the-product-of-two-regular-ideals-of-an-order-of-an-algebraic-number-fie/560996#560996

Comment: At the same time, you post questions that seem to be small variations of each other (just looking at the "Proposition"): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557548/on-the-norm-formula-nij-ninj-in-an-order-of-an-algebraic-number-field?noredirect=1#comment1196793_557548 http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555640/norm-of-the-product-of-two-regular-ideals-of-an-order-of-an-algebraic-number-fie/560996#560996 . Neither has any explanation why you asked both of them. Instead, just post one question with both variants - or, better just ask one, and then work out the other for yourself.

Comment: @CarlMummert `[If you are asking for "alternative proofs", why do you write answers yourself? That seems to go against your argument that you are genuinely interesd in other answers.]`

When you ask alternative proofs, you need to show what your proof is, don't you?

Comment: The appearance instead is that you ask numerous questions for which the only answer is yours. So if your goal is truly to get others to comment on your proof (which, at the level of your questions, should not generally be necessary) then you should explain which part of your own proof you think is possibly problematic, rather than asking for other proofs. Or, if you want other proofs, don't post your own answers. But there are many other issues with the way your questions are written. You might try imitating other more well voted questions, and also asking fewer, more valuable, questions.

Comment: @CarlMummert `[At the same time, you post questions that seem to be small variations of each other]`

The one is a generalization of the other.
I hadn't known the possibility of the generalization when I asked the former.
I added explanations on both questions.

Comment: I do not think it is an appropriate use of the site to simultaneously (within the a few days) ask a minor variation of the a question you have just asked, when the original does not even have an accepted answer. Let someone answer the first one, and then see if you can prove the generalization yourself without posting it as another question. This is a specific case of my general advice to ask fewer, more valuable questions, in order to encourage other people to participate in them.

Comment: @CarlMummert `[I do not think it is an appropriate use of the site to simultaneously (within the a few days) ask a minor variation of the a question you have just asked, when the original does not even have an accepted answer.]`
It's not a minor variation. It's big improvement.
However, this does not mean the former lost its value.
As you see, their proofs are very different.
Each proof has its own meirt.

Comment: @CarlMummert `[Let someone answer the first one, and then see if you can prove the generalization yourself without posting it as another question.]`
I already proved the former.
I don't see why I should not post the latter until someone will provide an alternative proof of the former.

Answer (score 9):

I am sad to say that reading this discussion left me no other logical alternative but to vote to close the question that initiated this round of exchanges.

The way I see it Makoto Kato's modus operandi is to repeatedly plea to that blog post by Joel Spolsky for justification of his actions. Furthermore he is continuously asking downvoters to explain what exactly should be corrected in the questions for them to be acceptable. The problem with that is that the need to define a function (one returning a Yes/No answer in response to a text to be posted), or a **binding** list of criteria for acceptability, should not arise in the first place. Even though this is a programming/math site, we cannot rely on such definitions alone on matters of judgement. I'm not the first to quote justice Stewart here, but if courts of law are unwilling to give a precise definition, and use the principle [I know it when I see it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_know_it_when_I_see_it) when judging a case, then
I don't think that we should be bothered either.

Because of this wider context I am unwilling to judge this post on its own merits alone, moderator's pleas notwithstanding. Does that form an ad hominem -attack? Possibly? I'm not good at critically studying my subconscious. But I know that the members enraged by Makoto's antics are intelligent and knowledgable people. They know [history of ancient Athens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostracism), and are aware of what may go wrong, if we start ostracizing people indiscriminately.

Note that [similar attempts at blogging on MSE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3797/11619) (by others!) have been shot down in the past by the community.

Comment: I'm sure you are aware that the "I know it when I see it" test for obscenity was subsequently superseded by the [Miller test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_test).

Comment: In short, you are just saying that you voted to close my question because you think it should be closed. I don't see anything logical here.

Answer (score 0):

Closings, downvotes and suspensions are not necessarily rational processes on the main site and even less so on the meta.  I have never downvoted or close-voted any of your material, may have upvoted some of it, do not believe that negative votes on the main site are useful, and don't agree with the generalized idea of "not using SE as a blog".  I also considered your recent suspension, like most of the other suspensions noticed on meta, to be ridiculous.

Having said that: the style of your recent postings is awful no matter who posts them, the rate of posting, or the possible use of MSE as a blog.

- they are **much longer than needed** to state the question using standard words
- they contain huge amounts of **meta comments in the postings**, about your intentions, interests, or justification for posting the question.  This is useless and destroys readability.  Descriptions of yourself belong in the user profile, not the question.
- unnecessary comments about the relations to some deep and important theory sound like **promotion of the question**.
- there are **no published sources** given as evidence that the statements in the question are correct or were ever considered interesting.
- it is therefore **unclear if the question is correct or interesting**. Very few people will be interested in checking your proofs to guess whether the statement is correct.   The SE technology is not designed to operate as a personal tutorial site that interactively debugs posters' "work and effort".
- you ask for **intellectually limited answers** by requesting elementary and complete proofs.
- there are **hints and spoiler space in the question**. This belongs only in an answer containing your solutions, hints, or other writings.
- the links that create **dependency on a cloud of other questions**.  Nobody is interested in tracing through a forest of other postings that (for the above reasons) might be nothing more than a narration of your intuitions instead of a body of known theory.  Maybe it is all correct, or maybe not, but nobody is going to spend the time to decide which is the case.

There are other problems [edit: such as using identical, cut-and-paste **boilerplate text** in many different postings, which can be considered a form of **spam**] but that should give a sufficient idea.

I do think there is a group of people who automatically downvote and close-vote your postings on both sites.   Re-working the questions in fear of suspensions and close votes, by adding extra material (such as "context, effort and motivation") is only making these questions worse.

Comment: I edited the question to make it shorter and clearer recently. Have you noticed that?

Comment: I have seen a few versions of your question, probably all of them, and including the latest one.  But I am also referring to other questions with the same stylistic problems.

Comment: `[they contain huge amounts of meta comments in the postings, about your intentions, interests, or justification for posting the question. This is useless and destroys readability. Descriptions of yourself belong in the user profile, not the question.]`

I used to ask questions without writing those.
Some people downvoted for them or voted to close them because thay think they lack context.
I didn't much care.
However, recently a new rule that a question lacking context or effort should be closed was introduced. So I began to write context, motivation, etc.

Comment: Yes, that is a problem with the "context missing" closing pressure.  It is clearly making some questions worse by the addition of useless material that makes the question less clear, longer, less readable.

Comment: `[there are no published sources given as evidence that the statements in the question are correct or were ever considered interesting.]`
I don't understand why this is a problem.

Comment: It reduces the expertise of the answers, since fewer knowledgeable people will be interested in responding, and your own answers are unclear as to their correctness.  Not because there is anything known to be wrong in them (that would require checking them in detail to find out), but because you operate without any known synchronization mechanism to outside knowledge.  The usual method for synchronization is published references, the kind that are read by a larger number of people, checked by referees, usually known to experts to be correct or wrong, and use relatively standard terminology.

Comment: +1 for the list, -1 for the first paragraph.

Comment: @zyx I really don't understand why it is a problem.
I guess there are some misunderstandings between us.
You don't mean that a question in this site should have published sources which support its correctness, do you?

Comment: I certainly *do* mean that a source should be given whenever possible.  Not only as evidence of correctness, but that is the relevant application in your case.

Comment: @zyx What if I don't know such a source? You think a question without such a source should be frowned upon?

Comment: Then there are two consequences.  For a single question, its quality is usually worse than if you did have a source.  For a large body of questions, it starts to become a cloud that floats away from the known set of mathematics and become a "single-person isolated mathematics" whose rate of correctness is at some increasingly unknown point between 0 and 100 percent.  Since you do not usually reference outside sources and other people do not refer to your postings, the chances of people interacting enough with what you write to either verify the correctness or catch the mistakes, decreases.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, if the opinions were universal there would be no need to mention them. Some of those things needed to be said given the current environment.

Comment: @zyx `[The other stylistic problems can be corrected, but if you build things without sources and with most questions having only your own answers, there is no error-correction process taking place.]`

If the only person who knows my answers is me, I guess you are right.
But it's unlikely because any user of this site can see them.

Comment: The "error-correction process" would involve other people, hopefully some of them experts, commenting for or against the correctness of the source-less material.   This is obviously not happening.  When nobody comes forward to answer the question (in a relatively popular tag among experts using MSE), and number of page views is low, that is evidence of nobody reading your proofs, not that the proofs are correct. If the postings were written in a different way (such as adding sources) the fraction of people who read them closely might be larger.  Currently it seems close to zero.

Comment: @zyx `[This is obviously not happening.]`
For example, please see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555379/factor-ring-by-a-regular-ideal-of-a-one-dimensional-noetherian-domain)
,[this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555045/determination-of-the-prime-ideals-lying-over-2-in-a-quadratic-order),
[this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158876/ideal-class-group-of-a-one-dimensional-noetherian-domain),
[this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183522/unramification-of-a-prime-ideal-in-an-order-of-a-finite-galois-extension-of-an-a).

Comment: What percentage of your questions (without a source, and requesting a proof) show evidence of others reading your arguments and forming a decision about correctness?  You have 53 questions with $0$ answers. There are 244 with $1$ answer, and many of those are your own answers, but I don't know how to count that subset automatically, or the number of proofs that are logically dependent on un-reviewed arguments in your questions and answers.

Comment: For example, the answers to your [alternative-proof] questions in the graduate-school level of tags like algebraic number theory and commutative algebra, are mainly from you, or the questions are not answered.  A few questions get outside answers, but this is the exception, and in your examples we see things like expert answers to parts 1-2 of a 6 part question, with the other 4 in an answer you wrote, including claims (no.5) listed as nontrivial.  http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A28422+[alternative-proof]+

Comment: @zyx `[What percentage of your questions (without a source, and requesting a proof) show evidence of others reading your arguments and forming a decision about correctness?]`
Here(http://math.stackexchange.com/users/28422/makoto-kato?tab=questions&sort=votes
) is the first page of the list of all of my questions.
Most of them were answered by others.

Comment: Bad statistics. If you want to use the Votes sorting, maybe we should also look at the *last (several) pages* of lowest voted questions and not only the *first page* of highest voted questions.  Most of the first page are there because they are elementary questions outside your specialization, or in general popular tags like [tag:soft-question] and [tag:math-history]), or do contain references, or were posted in a relatively reasonable style before the start of the last few months of "new posting technique" described in my answer.

Comment: For better examples, try this: http://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a28422%20[algebraic-number-theory]%20is%3aquestion .  In your last 15 [algebraic-number-theory] questions, basically the last two months of "new style" posts, there were 11 answers, of which you authored 10.  That's **one** independent answer to 15 questions.  Looking at the earlier questions, they either gave references or were in a simpler style of asking a short mathematics question.  The new method makes replies much less likely.

Comment: @zyx `[The new method makes replies much less likely.]`

I think this is not my fault. I cannot go back to the old style because of the new rule of closing a question, can I?

Comment: "How to ask a good question": http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960

Comment: Makoto: I think you may have misinterpreted the practices for closing (there aren't hard-and-fast "rules", of course). Questions are sometimes closed, among other reasons, for not including context and simply stating a problem. But what you are adding isn't "context" as I understand it - the place you encountered the problem, why the problem is generally interesting, and the specific issue(s) you are worried about. In at least one question, you added an argument why the question should not be closed and your personal intent for the question, which isn't the type of context I look for.

Comment: @CarlMummert `[But what you are adding isn't "context" as I understand it]`
Isn't providing outline of the proof enough?

Comment: @zyx `[you ask for intellectually limited answers by requesting elementary and complete proofs.]`
I don't know what's wrong with this.
In my opinion, a detailed proof is almost always better than terse one.
You can always skip an easy step if you want.
On the other hand, it might take a *long* time to fill in a gap of a terse proof.
Or even worse, you might never be able to do it.
Anyway, I changed the wording "please" to "I wish".
So it's rather my wish than my request now.